# trigger onscroll() on p-tree for lazyloading parent nodes

Tags: angular

I am a beginner to angular and trying hard to get the scroll postion so that I can load more items once user reaches the bottom. To start with, I just want to capture scroll position .how I can trigger the event once user reaches the bottom?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tree-demo-5p3mvs?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

In your template:

```
<div (scrolled)="onScrollDown()">
```

In your ts

```
onScrollDown() {
  // increment some counter
  // fetch data
}
```

For reference [check this](https://houssein.me/progressive-angular-applications-2)